# Is nematic ordering time-reversal invariant?

Tags: symmetry-breaking, crystals, time-reversal-symmetry

I am confused about the definition of nematic order in crystals. In this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/nmat4138, they say that nematic order is "a lowering of the rotational symmetry while time-reversal invariance is preserved", while in this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3456, they say that it is just when "the crystal rotation symmetry is spontaneously broken". Which is it, and why?

Answer (score 3):

Nematic ordering is a breakdown of rotational symmetry, and does not involve breaking time-reversal symmetry. The two references you give do not contradict each other, the first just emphasizes that time-reversal symmetry is preserved.

This fact is obvious when you look at the isotropic to nematic transition of liquid crystals (where nematicity originated from essentially). Here you have the polymers start out randomly oriented, and then they order by lining up. If you just look at the phase where the polymers are lined up, nothing changes by reversing time, it is simply a spatial ordering.

Take a look at the image below, which emphasizes that nematic/smectic/crystalline transitions are simply spatial orderings.

[image: https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/imgs/512/208/2808010/PMC2808010_ijms-10-04772f1.png]

Comment: If you are right about the first source only emphasizing that the system has time-reversal symmetry, then the wording is confusing. However, I think the wording is correct. Here is another paper which says that same thing: <https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2877>. In the text of the paper they say, "However, fluctuations split the two transitions and give rise to an intermediate phase at $T_{mag} < T < T_{nem}$, where the tetragonal symmetry is broken but the spin-rotational $O(3)$ symmetry is not... This is by definition a nematic order...".

Comment: My apologies, I don't quite understand your confusion. The references you give all seem to say the same thing: that TR symmetry is preserved in the nematic transition. The nematic transition is the breaking of some higher rotational symmetry group to $C_2$ symmetry.

Comment: For example, in the reference you gave in the comment. If the spin-rotational symmetry was broken, then you would break time-reversal symmetry (net magnetization), but the authors emphasize that spin-rotation symmetry is not broken. In other words, the nematic phase respects TR symmetry.

Comment: To me, the wording implies that time-reversal symmetry and broken rotational symmetry are both aspects of nematic order. I guess this is not right. It is confusing to me because it seems like anisotropic is a more suitable word. I thought maybe the terminology was used differently in lattices versus liquid crystals, but I am having trouble finding a precise definition for nematic in the former case.

Comment: The terminology is the same for lattices and liquid crystals (which is why the terminology is borrowed in the first place). It is the breakdown of rotational symmetry to $C_2$. Anisotropic is the wrong word,  because even a square lattice is anisotropic (does not respect arbritrary rotations,  just 90deg ones, unlike a liquid). I recommend reading the textbook by Chaikin on the topic of symmetry breaking to get the full scope on symmetries and terminology.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll read the book.